# How to get a different number each month in sql?

Tags: sql, parameters, inner-join, between

What I'm trying to do is to get an amount for each month.

Would this work?

```
SELECT @location
       ,sum(x.amount) as Tot_amount
FROM this_table2 y

    INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT 
            SUM(x.amount)  
        FROM 
            this_table x 
        WHERE 
            x.date BETWEEN '1/1/14' AND '1/31/14') January_tot

LEFT JOIN this_table2 y
       on x.no = y.no
WHERE y.desc = 'INCOME' AND x.date between '1/1/14' and 'now
```

And if that does work, is there a way to set a parameter for the year? Also, how would I put the where clause after this?

Comment: Please fix your question. At its current edition it looks like if you have discussed the problem with us for hours and we know the underlying queries and table structures. In short: give more details

Comment: No, what you have written would not work.  SQL queries start with `SELECT`, not with `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to do it, the date_part function is essential for this.

```
select @location
      ,sum(x.amount) as Tot_amount
      ,sum(case when date_part('month', x.date) = 1 and date_part('year', x.date) = 2014 then amount end) as January_Tot
      sum(case when date_part('month', x.date) = 2 and date_part('year', x.date) = 2014 then amount end) as February_Tot

left join this_table2 y
      on x.no = y.no
where y.desc = 'INCOME' and x.date between '1/1/14' and current_date
```